# Exception "node is used in a different document than the one that created it" using C++ xerces library

Tags: c++, xml, dom, xerces, xerces-c

I have extracted a `DomNode` from a XML. I then tried to insert it to another `DomNode` located in a different `DOMDocument` using `appendChild(DOMNode*)` but I got a `DOMException`.

The exception:

> node is used in a different document than the one that created it

The question:

How can I move a `DomNode` from one `DOMDocument` to another?

Comment: Create a new node that is a copy of the node you extracted.

Comment: thanxs john for ur comment, but it will not work as i have tried using clone but it dn't work. while i have resolve the issue, after going through API i find one importNode(DOMNode*, bool), which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I go ahead an answer this question, The person who asked the question led me to this answer but it took some time for me to figure out the whole concept.

```
// Result is from an xpath query
while(result->iterateNext())
{
  // Creating the new document
  DOMDocument * doc  = this->domImplementation->createDocument();

  // Importing the node from the old document to the new document scope
  DOMNode     * node = doc->importNode(result->getNodeValue(), true);

  // Appending the node to the new document
  doc->appendChild(node);

  ...
```

As seen above, first you need to import the node to the document to give the node an owner document, then append it to that document where ever you want it to be placed.